# MAAS enlistment doesn't work, datasource not found, can't boot off of UEFI PXE

Tags: networking, server, uefi, maas, pxe

*Extremely detailed description of issue ahead, TL;DR servers I am trying to deploy can't enlist, and I am having UEFI netboot issues on a few of the servers*

I have 4 servers, (repurposed desktop towers, not a very serious home lab setup) with one of them serving the purpose of a dedicated region+rack controller (using a installed PostgreSQL database, MAAS version 2.8 installed via snap) (an old Dimension that works just for that reason). I had a previous setup with a lack of the listed issues, deployment went all fine until I reinstalled Ubuntu entirely to reset MAAS. (I accidently tried to DHCP assign 18Qt addresses across the IPv6/IPv4 range and the thing froze up, killing my network and thereafter Ubuntu refused to boot) The only difference since then was me setting up IPv6 on DD-WRT and a subnet change. (all IP addresses/references were changed and tested) Overall, MAAS has been a bit shaky after this reinstall but it might be the placebo effect.

A slight note for the below issue; I have been using DD-WRT/dnsmasq to control DHCP for my network, the MAAS controller can't really handle DHCP on top of its current load. All dhcp-boot records are intact and working (at least for IPv4, I am working on IPv6 netboot) (also, I know this setup isn't ideal, but once again, this isn't a very serious home lab setup, I am using MAAS for the convenience of scalability and centralized control, and I know not to expect much from this very, quite frankly, janky setup.)

2 out of the 3 virtualization host servers (which I am trying to deploy with MAAS, they are Dell Optiplex 3010s with latest BIOS updates) refuse to boot off of UEFI PXE, getting stuck on `Fetching netboot image...` The MAAS rackd.log says that the machine ended up grabbing `bootx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi` but nothing further than that. After attempting UEFI with Secure Boot on, I set the machine to boot with the legacy CSM. It ended up getting further than that all the way into the enlistment environment, but this leads into my next issue...

All 3 of the servers (including the one that worked over UEFI PXE, a HP 6300-SFF) refuse to enlist in the first place, saying `Can not apply stage final, no datasource found! Likely bad things to come!`. It then drops me to a sign in prompt under hostname `ubuntu` (not `maas-enlistment-node` like it should be). None of them were visible on the MAAS UI. It also failed to start the OpenSSH Daemon about 6 times earlier in the boot phase. My commissioning OS is Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa, which is also what the MAAS server runs on. (I have attempted Ubuntu 18.04 with the same results). On the sign in prompt, I tried all of the password combinations I could think of (`ubuntu`|`ubuntu`, `ubuntu`|`<nothing>`, `root`|`ubuntu`, `ubuntu`|`<my MAAS password>`, `maas`|`<MAAS password>`, etc.) and none of them would work. They all clearly had connectivity, as they were all given IP addresses by DD-WRT and they downloaded the netboot images and ephemeral ramdisk/I could ping them successfully on both their v4 and v6 addresses. All MAAS services were running, per the controllers panel.

I am not too sure on where to go from here. I had a functional installation before it died, and a reinstall and IPv6 deployment messes it all up. Log files and dnsmasq.conf available on request. TIA!

<sub>**(apologies if this is a bad/long post, its my first post, have been a long time lurker but not too familiar on how the structuring/moderation works here :P)**</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue after a long bout of fighting with the server. Apparently the PostgreSQL database had bad data in it, sending out false metadata to the hosts and multitudes more confusion. How it happened is beyond me, but I have migrated to a more ideal virtualized setup and it now works flawlessly along with Landscape. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯